# Sparse Matrix for real world datasets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, sparse-matrix, recommendation-engine

Can someone help me understand the process of creating Sparse Matrices for Recommender Systems in Python for real world datasets. All I see online are the datasets having customer ID or Item ID starting with 0 which is not valid in real world datasets.

Comment: If the only problem is having customer id=0 and/or item id=0, then you can always have a dictionary to map "production" customer id into "machine learning" customer id. for example: user_id "myusername1" => 0, "otheruser123" => 1, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had the same solution in mind but what about new customer IDs or Item IDs which will be coming in the future ? For that should I maintain a sorted list and add those customer IDs with their machine learning labels in a incremental way ?

Comment: New cust id and item id in the future can be assigned to higher "machine learning" id. But for current training those would not be needed anyway since sample data for those futures are not available. When new customer and new item is added you will need to retrain the model.